# Opencart does not show coupon box

Tags: opencart

I have a site http://www.pentrim.com - when you click on the cart it takes you to a page where it asks you to enter a gift voucher - I want to replace this with a coupon box!

I have added a coupon to the opencart backend, but the box does not appear - which makes me think there may be something missing in my template or opencart configuration.

Can somebody help me determine what is missing?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your source: catalog\view\theme\pentrim\template\checkout\cart.tpl

Find & remove below code from cart.tpl file.

```
<?php if ($coupon_status || $voucher_status || $reward_status || $shipping_status) { ?>
  <h2><?php echo $text_next; ?></h2>
  <div class="content">
    <p><?php echo $text_next_choice; ?></p>
    <table class="radio">
      <?php if ($coupon_status) { ?>
      <tr class="highlight">
        <td><?php if ($next == 'coupon') { ?>
          <input type="radio" name="next" value="coupon" id="use_coupon" checked="checked" />
          <?php } else { ?>
          <input type="radio" name="next" value="coupon" id="use_coupon" />
          <?php } ?></td>
        <td><label for="use_coupon"><?php echo $text_use_coupon; ?></label></td>
      </tr>
      <?php } ?>
      <?php if ($voucher_status) { ?>
      <tr class="highlight">
        <td><?php if ($next == 'voucher') { ?>
          <input type="radio" name="next" value="voucher" id="use_voucher" checked="checked" />
          <?php } else { ?>
          <input type="radio" name="next" value="voucher" id="use_voucher" />
          <?php } ?></td>
        <td><label for="use_voucher"><?php echo $text_use_voucher; ?></label></td>
      </tr>
      <?php } ?>
      <?php if ($reward_status) { ?>
      <tr class="highlight">
        <td><?php if ($next == 'reward') { ?>
          <input type="radio" name="next" value="reward" id="use_reward" checked="checked" />
          <?php } else { ?>
          <input type="radio" name="next" value="reward" id="use_reward" />
          <?php } ?></td>
        <td><label for="use_reward"><?php echo $text_use_reward; ?></label></td>
      </tr>
      <?php } ?>
      <?php if ($shipping_status) { ?>
      <tr class="highlight">
        <td><?php if ($next == 'shipping') { ?>
          <input type="radio" name="next" value="shipping" id="shipping_estimate" checked="checked" />
          <?php } else { ?>
          <input type="radio" name="next" value="shipping" id="shipping_estimate" />
          <?php } ?></td>
        <td><label for="shipping_estimate"><?php echo $text_shipping_estimate; ?></label></td>
      </tr>
      <?php } ?>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="cart-module">
    <div id="coupon" class="content" style="display: <?php echo ($next == 'coupon' ? 'block' : 'none'); ?>;">
      <form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <?php echo $entry_coupon; ?>&nbsp;
        <input type="text" name="coupon" value="<?php echo $coupon; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="coupon" />
        &nbsp;
        <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $button_coupon; ?>" class="button" />
      </form>
    </div>
    <div id="voucher" class="content" style="display: <?php echo ($next == 'voucher' ? 'block' : 'none'); ?>;">
      <form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <?php echo $entry_voucher; ?>&nbsp;
        <input type="text" name="voucher" value="<?php echo $voucher; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="voucher" />
        &nbsp;
        <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $button_voucher; ?>" class="button" />
      </form>
    </div>
    <div id="reward" class="content" style="display: <?php echo ($next == 'reward' ? 'block' : 'none'); ?>;">
      <form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <?php echo $entry_reward; ?>&nbsp;
        <input type="text" name="reward" value="<?php echo $reward; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="reward" />
        &nbsp;
        <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $button_reward; ?>" class="button" />
      </form>
    </div>
    <div id="shipping" class="content" style="display: <?php echo ($next == 'shipping' ? 'block' : 'none'); ?>;">
      <p><?php echo $text_shipping_detail; ?></p>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_country; ?></td>
          <td><select name="country_id">
              <option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>
              <?php foreach ($countries as $country) { ?>
              <?php if ($country['country_id'] == $country_id) { ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $country['country_id']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $country['name']; ?></option>
              <?php } else { ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $country['country_id']; ?>"><?php echo $country['name']; ?></option>
              <?php } ?>
              <?php } ?>
            </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_zone; ?></td>
          <td><select name="zone_id">
            </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><span id="postcode-required" class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_postcode; ?></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="postcode" value="<?php echo $postcode; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_quote; ?>" id="button-quote" class="button" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
```

**Add Below code instead of above remove code:**

```
<div id="coupon" class="content">
      <form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <?php echo $entry_coupon; ?>&nbsp;
        <input type="text" name="coupon" value="<?php echo $coupon; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="coupon" />
        &nbsp;
        <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $button_coupon; ?>" class="button" />
      </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should go to extensions>order totals>copoun then change the status to be enabled